# Prove multivariable limit to infinite

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm pretty sure that $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (1,1)} \frac{y+1}{\sqrt{x^{2}-1}} =+\infty $$ However I want to prove it. In order to do so, I think I must find an $M$ such that $$ \frac{y+1}{\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}>M$$ when $$0<\sqrt{(x-1)^{2}+(y-1)^{2}}<\delta$$ but until now I couldn't find it. Can you give some help? Furthermore, is there another way to solve this limit?

Comment: Hint: Choose $\delta < 1/2$ and then we have that $\frac{y+1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} \leq \frac{3/2}{1/\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{x-1}} = \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}} \rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: There is an issue that if $0 \lt x \lt 1$ then $\frac{y+1}{\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}$ is not real.